# XPath selecting multiple elements with predicates

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an XPath query which is doing what I want, namely selecting a union of 'surname' & 'given-names' with the given predicates (It's actually either/or that I need, but the union works fine):

```
/header/authors/surname[./text() and @id='1']
|
/header/authors/given-names[./text() and @id='1']
```

However this seems overly long-winded to me and I feel that it should be possible to do something more succinct such as:

```
/header/authors/(surname|given-names)[./text() and @id='1']
```

... but this version is not valid XPath.

Can anyone tell me of a neater way of writing the original XPath expression which doesn't require the full path to be written twice?

Thanks

Richard

Comment: What do you mean by "either/or"?

Comment: @Alejandro: Given an id, the required element could be 'surname' or 'given-names'. That's what I was trying to say. I think it is the union which I need.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, this is valid XPath 2.0:

```
/header/authors/(surname|given-names)[./text() and @id='1']
```

Second, this XPath 1.0:

```
/header/authors/*[self::surname|self::given-names][text()][@id='1']
```

Comment: This is excellent and I was about to +1 it. However, in the XPath 1.0 version it is better not to use `|` inside of the predicate. The correct operator is `or`. In this case the expression still selects the wanted nodes, but in other cases substituting `or` with `|` does not produce an equivalent expression. +1, anyway.

Comment: @Dimitre: You are right about `|` union set operator, but I've used it **in this case**, because both terms are node sets (and because succinct was the key). The same goes for predicates sequence.

Comment: This answer explains both why I felt that I should to be able to use `(surname|given-names)` (the current project is not using XPath 2.0) and also provided a great XPath 1.0 alternative. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
/header/authors/*[(name() = "surname" or name()="given-names") and ./text() and @id='1']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does save writing the path out twice, but still is somewhat unwieldy compared to what I had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Alejandro's and Seva's good answers, another alternative is

```
(/header/authors/surname | /header/authors/given-names)[text() and @id='1']
```

This is valid in XPath 1.0. It still is a bit redundant, but is more succinct than the long-winded version in your question.

A further alternative would be to declare a variable for surname elements and a variable for given-name elements, and then

```
($surnames | $given-names)[text() and @id='1']
```

That would probably be longer in total, but easier to read than the above.