# XPath group multiple tags

Tags: javascript, xpath, merge, tags

I use the following XPath to get all non-empty text and image nodes from a document, except those within the div with id 'mpp_controls':

```
//img[not(ancestor::*[@id='mpp_controls'][normalize-space()])] | //text()[not(ancestor::*[@id='mpp_controls'])][normalize-space()]
```

Since the predicates are the same for both elements, and I might add more tags to similar queries in the future, I tried to shorten it. Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079565/xpath-selecting-multiple-elements-with-predicates#answer-4079705) I came up with:

```
//*[self::img or self::text()][not(ancestor::*[@id='mpp_controls'])][normalize-space()]
```

And I also tried:

```
//*[img or text()][not(ancestor::*[@id='mpp_controls'])][normalize-space()]
```

Both give me a syntax error, unfortunately. Is it at all possible to shorten this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` means "element". Naturally this excludes text nodes.

Also, your conditions can be combined in a single predicate.

```
//node()[
  (self::img or self::text())
  and normalize-space()
  and not(ancestor::*[@id='mpp_controls'])
]
```

An alternative is

```
(//img | //text()[normalize-space()])[
  not(ancestor::*[@id='mpp_controls'])
]
```

Note how you can use parentheses to apply a predicate to a union.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I really like the format of the alternative. Now I should be able to form all the queries that I need for my current project!

Comment: The alternative also should be a little more efficient because it works on less nodes to begin with.