# XPath how to select all either div or td's with the same class?

Tags: xpath

How do I select all `div`'s or `td`'s with the same set of attributes.

Given some fingerprint features like className is there an easier way to select a well defined subset of element types with xpath, than to concatenate all different element types (and fingerprint attribs) with `|`.

I know I can write:

```
//div[@class="myClass"]|//td[@class="myClass"]
```

but since my fingerprint attributes are long and complex (this is grossly simplified) I was hoping for something in the neighbourhood of this:

```
//(div|td)[@class="myClass"]
```

but it does not seem to work out for me

Comment: can you please provide some xml document.

Comment: I found an answer here on stacktrace and posted it below. Thanks for the interest though! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I had searched stackoverflow thoroughly, but I just found an answer here: [XPath selecting multiple elements with predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079565/xpath-selecting-multiple-elements-with-predicates)

and it seems like:

```
//*[self::div|self::td][@class="myclass"]
```

does the trick

(please comment here if `//*` makes everything 1000 times slower, or if I might have missed something important ;) )